# Can visible light be used for measuring phonon dispersion relation?

Tags: visible-light, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, dispersion, phonons

As phonon dispersion realtions can be studied using inelastic scattering of neutrons with phonons and X-ray. So, can visible light be used to do so?

Comment: I presume you mean 'measuring' instead of 'calculating'. As for using visible light, consider the momentum of the photon, and the range of momentum across the unit cell. How much of the first Brillouin zone can you access with a visible photon?

Comment: @SeemaChahal Adding to the previous comment, neutrons being neutral particles are very effective at transferring the energy directly to the lattice and not to the electron cloud surrounding it, leading to very high precision penetration.